# How do I decrypt an encrypted private key in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I have an encrypted private key and a passphrase. How do I decrypt the private key in ColdFusion?

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
{THE_ENCRYPTED_PRIVATE_KEY}
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In PHP it's possible to do this, but I can't find an equivalent in ColdFusion.

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($private_key, $passphrase);
```

I've tried using the `decrypt()` method which didn't work.

Comment: You would need to do this in Java.

Comment: How was the original encryption done?

Comment: Yes, what was the origin of this encryption? Was that done in CF or some other tool? You need to provide some code or context to your question.

Comment: If you can decrypt with php, it was probably encrypted with php.  If that's the case, write a php webservice that does the decryption and call it with ColdFusion.

Comment: I looked at the docs for `openssl_pkey_get_private` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php), and it's talking about PEM encoding/formatting. I then googled PEM java and the first match for me was https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-pem-file-keys, which seems pretty easy to follow, and looks to be what you need. There's no native CFML way of doing this, that I'm aware of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any information about how the original encryption was done. Thanks, Adam. I'll take a look.